# what is different between 'babel-plugin-module-resolver' and 'tsconfig-paths'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, next.js

i find a **SSR** demo (React+typescript+Next.js),and its used these two plugins.

i was confused that why its need **both of them**?

As far as I am concerned,these two plugins did the **same work**,anyone can explain why?

> tsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
        "@components/*": [
            "./components/*"
        ],
        "@helper/*": [
            "./helper/*"
        ],
        "@utils/*": [
            "./utils/*"
        ],
        "@interfaces/*": [
            "./interfaces/*"
        ],
        "@api/*": [
            "./pages/api/*"
        ],
        "@serverApi/*": [
            "./server/api/*"
        ],
        "@newscenter/*": [
            "./newscenter/*"
        ],
        "@spotcenter/*": [
            "./spotcenter/*"
        ],
        "@styles/*": [
            "./styles/*"
        ]
    }
```

> .babelrc

```
 "plugins": [
    [
        "module-resolver",
        {
            "root": ["./"],
            "alias": {
                "@components": "./components",
                "@helper": "./helper",
                "@utils": "./utils",
                "@interfaces": "./interfaces",
                "@api": "./pages/api",
                "@serverApi": "./server/api",
                "@newscenter": "./newscenter",
                "@spotcenter": "./spotcenter",
                "@styles": "./styles"
            }
        }
    ]
]
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Both are doing the same end result but one of them for Typescript the other for Javascript

Answer (score 3):

This is an old questions. but for anyone coming across this in future I thought I'd update.

jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you're using typescript) is to inform your IDE that you are using these aliases. vscode or intellij for example, will then know where to look to check your imports are working correctly

the module resolver plugin for babel is what tells the server to import the files from those aliases